# Why does bingbot access my sites the most even if I set crawl rate to the minmum?

Tags: web-crawlers, performance, bingbot, crawl-rate

Recently my sites got overloaded and it turned out bingbot was the culprit. I set the crawl rate for the minimum for my sites in bing webmaster tools, but regardless bingbot has the most access (about 30000 requests a day) among all the crawlers. Google has less requests a day.

Do you also experience heavy traffic from bingbot? Why doesn't it behave when I set crawling rate to a minimum?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is really a Bing bot? I have seen bots that ignore disallows that turned out to be from somewhere other than expected when doing a reverse IP lookup using dig.

```
dig -x 157.55.39.142

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> -x 157.55.39.142
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30244
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;142.39.55.157.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
142.39.55.157.in-addr.arpa. 71  IN      PTR     msnbot-157-55-39-142.search.msn.com.

;; Query time: 57 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 12 18:18:06 EDT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104
```

The reverse lookup shows the IP is indeed related to Bing's search bots.

They do state that the crawl control directive in a robots.txt file will take precedence over a configured setting on their end.

http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/crawl-control-55a30302

If that doesn't seem to be the case you may want to try using their controls to adjust their crawl for your site.

Comment: It is bingbot, the requests are coming from the 157.55.... range and reverse lookup points to bingbot. I haven't tried the robots.txt method yet (I thought using their controls is enough), but I'll give it a try.